# Wicket/Java UI framework Development

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, jakarta-ee, wicket

I am quite used to creating user interfaces with HTML/CSS/JS. However, I am working on a JAVA application that utilizes Wicket.

Can anyone point to me anything that shows how to create a ui with Wicket, from a stand point such as mine? If that makes sense. I have been trying to understand how I am going to develop the UI after reading many articles and meeting with our developers. I am just not wrapping my head around how to do it.

Also, from what I know, does it make sense to actually use Wicket when you have a ui designer and developer on staff who can create an MVC UI from scratch?

Please, if this doesn't make sense I hope you feel compelled to ask questions to pull whatever info you need and I am not saying. I am desperately trying to figure a.) does wicket make sense still, b.)how in the heck do I build a UI using it!

Comment: If you get interested in Wicket Development, I recommend the book Wicket in Action http://wicketinaction.com/downloads/ , it is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can't get better than the examples in wicketstuff. You can just parse through the [forminput sample](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/forminput). The sourcecode button is on right top.

There is indeed a small curve related to getting started with wicket as it changes the complete direction of thinking towards web GUI.

Basically, the idea of wicket is to have HTML template pages with some wicket markup placeholders that will be filled by the parallel java class.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to start looking at wicket tutorials [on the official Wicket website](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/). Then there is wicketstuff, which also has a very comprehensive collection as mentioned by Suraj Chandran. Most examples show you both Java and the associated HTML markup.

Even if you are not a Java developer it would be beneficial for you to understand how different Wicket markup tags get interpreted and how a Wicket-based application is built from several HTML pages, borders, panels and other Wicket-related components.

Wicket is very good for separating Java code from HTML (much better than frameworks that use JSP, PHP, and other technologies that mix code with HTML). Because there is no Java source code in the HTML pages it makes it easier for designers to work independently of the developers. Also HTML files can be edited in HTML editor programs like Dreamweaver directly.

If you are a Dreamweaver user and are familiar with Template and Library functions, then in the Wicket world you will find very similar concepts. Dreamweaver Template = Wicket Border, Dreamweaver Library Item = Wicket Panel, for example.